# I have a problem with kibana pie chart's colors palette

Tags: colors, elastic-stack, pie-chart, dashboard, kibana-7

I couldn't find how to change the colors in  pie charts and treemaps in my kibana's dashboard.
Does anyone know how to change the default colors of a pie chart in kibana 7.10.2  dashboards please ?

Answer (score 1):

Pie chart color can be picked in edit mode of concrete visualization, after clicking on legend. To show legend click bottom left icon.
[image: Pick color on pie visualization]

Im unaware of default scheme cross dashboard, however maybe if you export dashboard into json, then json can be edited and reimported again, instead of using UI mentioned above. Color is stored in property *uiStateJSON* like this:

```
"uiStateJSON":"{\"vis\":{\"colors\":{\"Count\":\"#629E51\",\"passed\":\"#508642\",\"failed\":\"#BF1B00\",\"pending\":\"#E5AC0E\"}}}"
```

In complex scenarios *Vega* visualization can be used, where common scheme can be defined with *[scale](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/scales/#range)* property.

```
"encoding": {
  "theta": {"field": "result_count", "type": "quantitative"},
  "color": {
    "field": "result_count",
    "type": "nominal",
    "scale": { "scheme": "reds" }
  }
}
```

or defined range scale property: `"scale": { "range": ["#FF5050","#50FF50"] }`

or merged color dimension with visualized data like it is done [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-C0k4gLIq5OvnBwHDu5zp13U4gPSHqnoezrN2quBeKuq6PiqukbBytq2A62yMs+2yfAqDRQF+6cYeBIC9FSBwWgVJH1S7OKEswpzvts5Hni9Cm3tInBUM6-rjtmkBhrOmQnxfOkv2vFRKDk7JFq0ygHRkVbcrOgrNrZhl0E-b9ub2nK2AbBtUg9ABaaogKuawPTWhGpbbTmf0oeWWvuhwAHkGigOhfkqhQb3QhBtAAXld7QZa538Nzxy6PjJsNpSu6UgA)